# How do I change cell height according to its content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Detail View Controller, which has different text lengths according to which cell you press in the Main View Controller, of which it segues to. How do I set the cell's height according to how much content is in it?

FYI, the cell consists of 3 labels and 1  image view. It is vertically set as `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, `UILabel`.

I am using Swift.

This is what happens when I add the auto-layout constraints:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your image? Could you post an image with your layouts?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Its not the image, its the text. How do I set it so that its height always fits the text? Read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I added the `sizeToFit()` property to my label.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to use auto-layout. You need to set up vertical constraints from the top to the bottom of your cell:

1. Distance between the top edge of the cell and the top edge of the first label.
2. Distance from the bottom edge of the first label to the top edge of the image view.
3. Distance from the bottom edge of the image view to the top edge of the second label.
4. and so on ...

Auto-layout will take care of sizing the cell depending on the size of the content you put in your labels and the image view.

You should also remember to set the `estimatedRowHeight` property on your table view to some meaningful value. This will help the table view defer some of the calculations of the content size to when the user starts to scroll.

Also, set the `rowHeight` property on your table view to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: I added what my simulator looks like when I added these constraints.

Comment: It only shows 4 lines, not the all the lines it is supposed to show.

Comment: Did you set up the last constraint from the bottom of the last label to the bottom of the cell? Did you set the `rowHeight` property on the table view to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` ?

Comment: Yes I did, its still the same.

Comment: How about the `numberOfLines` property on the label? It should be set to 0.

Comment: Is the bottom edge of the last label related to the bottom edge of the cell or the cell's content view? It should be the cell's content view. Plus all the subviews you've added should be children of the cell's content view.

Comment: All this has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 things you'll need to do:

1. Set your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
2. Set your `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` to return the average height of the cells. You can set it to something static like 100.
3. Set your Auto Layout constraints so that all subviews are tied to each other vertically, and the top-most and bottom-most views are tied up to the cell's `contentView`.
4. Set the label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property either in code or in your Storyboard to be equal to the label's width.

Comment: I added what you instructed, but the simulator still doesn't show all the text. See the image in the question.